# Strange Behaviour on Postgresql query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, sql-view

We created a view in Postgres and I am getting strange result.

View Name: `event_puchase_product_overview`

When I try to get records with `*`, I get the correct result. but when I try to get specific fields, I get wrong values.

I hope the screens attached here can explain the problem well.

```
select * 
from event_purchase_product_overview 
where id = 15065;
```

[image: img]

```
select id, departure_id 
from event_puchase_product_overview 
where id = 15065;
```

[image: img]

VIEW definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.event_puchase_product_overview AS 
 SELECT row_number() OVER () AS id,
    e.id AS departure_id,
    e.type AS event_type,
    e.name,
    p.id AS product_id,
    pc.name AS product_type,
    product_date.attribute AS option,
    p.upcomming_date AS supply_date,
    pr.date_end AS bid_deadline,
        CASE
            WHEN (pt.categ_id IN ( SELECT unnest(tt.category_ids) AS unnest
               FROM ( SELECT string_to_array(btrim(ir_config_parameter.value, '[]'::text), ', '::text)::integer[] AS category_ids
                       FROM ir_config_parameter
                      WHERE ir_config_parameter.key::text = 'trip_product_flight.product_category_hotel'::text) tt)) THEN e.maximum_rooms
            WHEN (pt.categ_id IN ( SELECT unnest(tt.category_ids) AS unnest
               FROM ( SELECT string_to_array(btrim(ir_config_parameter.value, '[]'::text), ', '::text)::integer[] AS category_ids
                       FROM ir_config_parameter
                      WHERE ir_config_parameter.key::text = 'trip_product_flight.product_category_flight'::text) tt)) THEN e.maximum_seats
            WHEN (pt.categ_id IN ( SELECT unnest(tt.category_ids) AS unnest
               FROM ( SELECT string_to_array(btrim(ir_config_parameter.value, '[]'::text), ', '::text)::integer[] AS category_ids
                       FROM ir_config_parameter
                      WHERE ir_config_parameter.key::text = 'trip_product_flight.product_category_bike'::text) tt)) THEN e.maximum_bikes
            ELSE e.maximum_seats
        END AS departure_qty,
        CASE
            WHEN now()::date > pr.date_end AND po.state::text = 'draft'::text THEN true
            ELSE false
        END AS is_deadline,
    pl.product_qty::integer AS purchased_qty,
    pl.comments,
    pl.price_unit AS unit_price,
    rp.id AS supplier,
    po.id AS po_ref,
    po.state AS po_state,
    po.date_order AS po_date,
    po.user_id AS operator,
    pl.po_state_line AS line_status
   FROM event_event e
     LEFT JOIN product_product p ON p.related_departure = e.id
     LEFT JOIN product_template pt ON pt.id = p.product_tmpl_id
     LEFT JOIN product_category pc ON pc.id = pt.categ_id
     LEFT JOIN purchase_order_line pl ON pl.product_id = p.id
     LEFT JOIN purchase_order po ON po.id = pl.order_id
     LEFT JOIN purchase_order_purchase_requisition_rel prr ON prr.purchase_order_id = po.id
     LEFT JOIN purchase_requisition pr ON pr.id = prr.purchase_requisition_id
     LEFT JOIN res_partner rp ON rp.id = po.partner_id
     LEFT JOIN ( SELECT p_1.id AS product_id,
            pav.name AS attribute
           FROM product_product p_1
             LEFT JOIN product_attribute_value_product_product_rel pa ON pa.prod_id = p_1.id
             LEFT JOIN product_attribute_value pav ON pav.id = pa.att_id
             LEFT JOIN product_attribute pat ON pat.id = pav.attribute_id
          WHERE pat.name::text <> ALL (ARRAY['Date'::character varying, 'Departure'::character varying]::text[])) product_date ON product_date.product_id = p.id
  WHERE (p.id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT mrp_bom_line.product_id
           FROM mrp_bom_line)) AND p.active
  ORDER BY e.id, pt.categ_id, p.id;
```

Comment: Is the column id present in the view? You cannot adress anything outside the view AFAIK. Adding the view code will help.

Comment: Yes, column_id is present in view. I put the defination here.

Comment: `row_number()` doesn't specify an `order by` so you will get different IDs for different rows every time you run the query.

Answer (score 0):

If I add new event_event or new product_product I'll get a new definition of row_number in my view, then the column ID of my view is not stable.

at least you can't use row_number as Id of the view,

If you insist to use row_number, you can use the Order By "creation DATE" by this way all new records will be as last lines in the view and this will not change the correspondency between ID (row_number) and other columns.

Hope that helps !

Comment: Okay, I understand well now, how about using a new table instead of a view, and add a new trigger in postgresql to update automatically the new table for every change in the event or product tables? by this way the IDs will never change

Answer (score 0):

Very likely the execution plan of your query depends on the columns you select. Compare the execution plans!

Your `id` is generated using the `row_number` window function. Now window functions are executed *before* the `ORDER BY` clause, so the order will depend on the execution plan and hence on the columns you select.

Using `row_number` without an explicit ordering doesn't make any sense.

To fix that, don't use

```
row_number() OVER ()
```

but

```
row_number() OVER (ORDER BY e.id, pt.categ_id, p.id)
```

so that you have a reliable ordering.

In addition, you should omit the `ORDER BY` clause at the end.